# Change value of a field after a form is validated in a Django Form

Tags: django-forms

In a Django Form POST method, I want to change a field value based on the `is_valid()` result. Thus, I can not change the value in a `clean_*` method as `is_valid()` would not be computed (nor be accessible).

Basically I need to change how the HTML appears based on a value (`is_cool` in the example below) dependent on the `is_valid()` result. This value then needs to be changed by the UI, if needed. In the template I have something like:

```
{% if record.is_cool %} something {% endif %}
```

Is this possibile or should I change the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The UI has to update the field value correctly, as is already doing now.

The View in Django can pass the condition `is_cool` without affecting the form and pass it to the template via the dict passed to the `render` function.

View code snippet:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {
    'record': form,
    'is_cool': True,
})
```

Template code would then change to something like:

```
{% if is_cool %} something {% endif %}
```

Note that the variables in the template `is_cool` and `record.is_cool` are different.